# The order of functions' execution in a high order function

Tags: haskell, happstack

I have a function here

```
(map (\ (a, b) -> dir a b) $ routes
```

where `routes` is a list of tuples and it contains

```
routes = [...
           ("graph-fb", seeOther redirectUrlGraphEmail $ toResponse ""),
           ("post-fb", seeOther redirectUrlGraphPost $ toResponse ""),
          ...]
```

Here is the question: when I call this function to apply dir on each tuple, which function is going to be returned as `b` in `dir a b` first, the function `seeOther redirectUrlGraphEmail` or `seeOther redirectUrlGraphEmail $ toResponse ""`?

Comment: Why does it matter? Just from the type of `map`, we know `dir` can't behave differently depending on what order it is fed arguments. This is not just a rhetorical question: I suspect if you say why you think it matters, you will reveal some confusion about Haskell that we can help clear up for you.

Comment: `routes` is not a function; it's a list.

Comment: Thanks @dfeuer for mentioning that. I already corrected this in the question.

Comment: And to answer @DanielWagner's question, I am confused because in haskell `$` has the lowest precedence. In this case, since first `redirectUrlGraphEmail` will be fed into `seeOther` as an argument, what will happen next is to return the value as `b` or is to apply `$` on `toResponse ""` ?

Answer (score 2):

Tuples items are separated by `,` which means that in your example for `graph-fb`,

```
a == "graph-fb"
b == seeOther redirectUrlGraphEmail $ toResponse ""
```

The first function call to resolve will be `toResponse ""`, and that will be fed into `seeOther` as the second parameter. The result of this will then have the label `b` inside the mapping function.

Comment: I understand what you said, but isn't `$` has the lowest precedence in haskell which makes `seeOther` to call `redirectUrlGraphEmail` first?

Comment: `$` has the lowest precedence compared to other infix operators. That whole bit on the right of the comma only contains a single infix operator, so it will be "bundled up" and labeled as `b` in the mapping function.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to tell from that code. Even ignoring the compiler's freedom to reorganize your program in various dramatic ways, the usual approach to Haskell evaluation is lazy, which you can think of as demand-driven, `case`-driven, and (ultimately) I/O-driven. Whoever actually inspects the results determines the evaluation order.